# Objective-C, Ads on a scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scrollview, ads, adwhirl

I'm currently using AdWhirl for my iOS app. I want to have my ads in the bottom of a scrollview. How can I achive that without Interface Builder, or can I use Interface builder?

Comment: Almost like a footer in the scroll view? Why not just make the UIScrollview shorter, and place the ad beneath it?

Comment: No, I'm nice to my users, they can scroll the ad away if they want to! So it has to be in the bottom of the scrollview!

Answer (score 0):

An initial look suggests that its simply a subclass of UIView. You can get the bounds of your UIScrollView add an instance of the AdWhirl view as a subview to the ScrollView and extend the content area.

Like any other view really.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use interface builder for that.

what you have to do is:-
you must be adding below lines in your viewDidLoad:-

```
AdWhirlView *awView = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self]; 
[self.view addSubview:awView];
```

You need to change  `[self.view addSubview:awView];` line to

```
[self.*yourscrollviewname* addSubview:awView];
```

then ads will be added in your scrollview.

for repositioning them  in AdWhirlView.h file find below lines and set the coordinates according to your requirement.

```
#define kAdWhirlViewDefaultFrame \
                        (CGRectMake(0,50,kAdWhirlViewWidth, kAdWhirlViewHeight))
```